# debugging odoo in intellij idea, odoo doesn't completely start up since upgrade to 2016.1.2

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea, odoo

This is what's printed on the console, If I start odoo with run instead of debug, it starts up normally, listens to 8069, and I can log in OK. Debug stopped working directly after the upgrade to 2016.1.2

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/michael/.IdeaIC2016.1/config/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 37758 --file openerp-server --database=kk3 --db-filter=kk3 --addons-path=addons,openerp/addons --update=kkproject,kkrockhopper,kkindex,kkrockhopperedi
pydev debugger: process 26288 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 145.972) 
2016-05-18 01:56:46,043 enter code here`26288 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0 
2016-05-18 01:56:46,044 26288 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/michael/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/home/michael/odoo/addons', u'/home/michael/odoo/openerp/addons'] 2016-05-18 01:56:46,044 26288 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost 
2016-05-18 01:56:46,044 26288 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432 
2016-05-18 01:56:46,044 26288 INFO ? openerp: database user: michael 
2016-05-18 01:56:46,232 26288 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Evented   
Service (longpolling) running on 0.0.0.0:8072
```

If I click stop, I get

```
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 

"/home/michael/.IdeaIC2016.1/config/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1531, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/michael/.IdeaIC2016.1/config/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 938, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
    openerp.cli.main()
  File "openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 68, in main
    o.run(args)
  File "openerp/cli/server.py", line 180, in run
    main(args)
  File "openerp/cli/server.py", line 174, in main
    rc = openerp.service.server.start(preload=preload, stop=stop)
  File "openerp/service/server.py", line 962, in start
    rc = server.run(preload, stop)
  File "openerp/service/server.py", line 419, in run
    self.start()
  File "openerp/service/server.py", line 408, in start
    self.httpd.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 349, in serve_forever
    self._stop_event.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/event.py", line 213, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/event.py", line 123, in _wait
    gotit = self._wait_core(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/event.py", line 101, in _wait_core
    result = self.hub.switch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 606, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
KeyboardInterrupt
2016-05-18 01:57:34,281 26288 ERROR ? openerp.service.server: Evented Service (longpolling): uncaught error during main loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openerp/service/server.py", line 408, in start
    self.httpd.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 349, in serve_forever
    self._stop_event.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/event.py", line 213, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/event.py", line 123, in _wait
    gotit = self._wait_core(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/event.py", line 101, in _wait_core
    result = self.hub.switch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 606, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw a hint about uninstalling gevent, and that worked for me. Strange because it stopped working after a intellij update. so:

```
apt-get purge python-gevent
pip uninstall gevent
```